# Magento2 Custom payment method not display in checkout page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-gateway

test\demo\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\method-renderer.js

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'webpay',
                component: 'test_demo/js/view/payment/method-renderer/webpay-method'
            }
        );
        /** Add view logic here if needed */
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

also test\demo\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\method-renderer\webpay-method.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
    'mage/url',
],
function (
    $,
    Component,
    placeOrderAction,
    selectPaymentMethodAction,
    customer,
    checkoutData,
    additionalValidators,
    url) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'test_demo/payment/webpay'
            },
            placeOrder: function (data, event) {
                if (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                var self = this,
                    placeOrder,
                    emailValidationResult = customer.isLoggedIn(),
                    loginFormSelector = 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]';
                if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $(loginFormSelector).validation();
                    emailValidationResult = Boolean($(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
                }
                if (emailValidationResult && this.validate() && additionalValidators.validate()) {
                    this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false);
                    placeOrder = placeOrderAction(this.getData(), false, this.messageContainer);

                    $.when(placeOrder).fail(function () {
                        self.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(true);
                    }).done(this.afterPlaceOrder.bind(this));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },

            selectPaymentMethod: function() {
                selectPaymentMethodAction(this.getData());
                checkoutData.setSelectedPaymentMethod(this.item.method);
                return true;
            },

            afterPlaceOrder: function () {
                window.location.replace(url.build('test/test/redirect/'));
            },
            /** Returns send check to info */
            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: `test_demo` is your custom module? Please add full path your js files.

Comment: test\demo\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment

Comment: yes custom module..

Comment: Tried to run static content deploy? There is a custom payment I have done: https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_Payment_Fee

Comment: thnx..working with deploy..

Comment: Can you please provide whole in one zip file , because i have tried all things but some js files are missing.. request to provide you.

Comment: @MagentoDevloper have you done  this?

Comment: yes..i have done with this code.

Comment: @MagentoDevloper Can you post your code as the answer or suggest me on this [thread](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150043/custom-payment-method-not-showing-in-checkout-page-in-magento-2). I am also facing same problem

Comment: can you share error??