# Custom Payment Method not showing in Checkout page in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods

I am created Custom Payment Method, but it is not showing on the checkout page. For this, I am written below code.

**etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="testpayment" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>TestPayment</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>New Order Status</label>
                    <source_model>Test\TestPayment\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\Pendingpayment</source_model>
                </field>

                <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="41" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
                <field id="instructions" translate="label" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Instructions</label>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                    <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
                </field>
            </group>
            <!-- payment-group -->
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <payment>
                <testpayment>
                <active>1</active>
                <title>Testpayment</title>
                <order_status>pending_payment</order_status>
                <instructions>Instruction.</instructions>
                <payment_action>true</payment_action>
                <model>Test\TestPayment\Model\Testpayment</model>
                <group>offline</group>
            </testpayment>
            </payment>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Test_TestPayment" setup_version="2.0.0">
  </module>
</config>
```

**etc/payment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Payment/etc/payment.xsd">
    <groups>
        <group id="offline">
            <label>Offline Payment Methods</label>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <methods>
        <method name="testpayment">
            <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
        </method>

    </methods>
</payment>
```

**Model/Config/Source/Order/Status/Pendingpayment.php**

```
 <?php
    namespace Test\TestPayment\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status;

    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status;

    /**
     * Order Status source model
     */
    class Pendingpayment extends Status
    {
        /**
         * @var string[]
         */
        protected $_stateStatuses = [Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT];
    }
```

**Model/Testpayment.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test\TestPayment\Model;

/**
 * Pay In Store payment method model
 */
class TestPayment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{

    /**
     * Payment code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'testpayment';

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isOffline = true;

}
```

**view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                                <item name="testpayment-testpayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Test_TestPayment/js/view/payment/testpayment</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                             <item name="testpayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            <!-- item-renderer -->
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-render/testpayment-method.js**

```
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Test_TestPayment/payment/testpayment'
            },

            /** Returns send check to info */
            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            }

        });
    }
);
```

**view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/testpayment.js**

```
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'testpayment',
                component: 'Test_TestPayment/js/view/payment/method-renderer/testpayment-method'
            }
        );
        /** Add view logic here if needed */
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

**view/frontend/web/template/payment/testpayment.html**

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_TestPayment',
    __DIR__
);
```

Could you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Comment: Can you share a github link for that module? It's too long.

Comment: @SohelRana Sorry, how to upload GitHub.

Comment: Create public repo and commit that repo. Share that link. OR somewhere upload it and share the link

Comment: @SohelRana plz navigate this link https://expirebox.com/download/19f8548bea1c179da79bd6edd2da28ae.html let me know if this link not working.

Comment: @SohelRana have you downloaded?

Comment: yes, I will be back after couple of hours later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your vendor name 'Test' to 'TestVendor'.

Your confix.xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <testpayment>
                <active>1</active>
                <title>Testpayment</title>
                <order_status>pending_payment</order_status>
                <instructions>Instruction.</instructions>
                <payment_action>true</payment_action>
                <model>TestVendor\TestPayment\Model\Testpayment</model>
                <group>offline</group>
            </testpayment>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="testpayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">TestVendor_TestPayment/js/view/payment/testpayment</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="testpayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Run setup:upgrade command and clear cache.

[Download From Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tialkoxbir8rw4p/TestVendor.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I tried that module in 2.1.3 and it gives errors expected instance of context found objectmanager, in apache error.log

Answer (score 3):

You should set `can_use_checkout` option to `1` in your `etc/config.xml` file.

To get more details about custom payments integrations, please, read [Integration Intro](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/integration-intro.html).

Also, check if you have any errors in browser console or exception log.

Comment: Its must required in config.xml like this, <can_use_checkout>1</can_use_checkout> for the Online Payment Gateway