# Insert custom block at payment Method section In Magento 2

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1, payment-methods

I have some **validations** to place order through custom **TestPayment** method, for this I have to **disable/enable** the **PlaceOrder** button and showing some **message** under my custom payment method section. For this I have created the [custom payment method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150043/custom-payment-method-not-showing-in-checkout-page-in-magento-2/150088#150088) and it is showing and working fine. But I don't know to to validate and showing messages here.

[image]

So Could you please suggest me how to **showing messages** and **enable/disable** **PlaceOrder** Button here based on **customer Data**.

**TestVendor/TestPayment/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/testpayment-method.js**

```
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'jquery'
    ],
    function (Component, customer, quote, $) {
        'use strict';

        var customer_Data;

        return Component.extend({

            defaults: {
                template: 'TestVendor_TestPayment/payment/testpayment'
            },

            /** Returns send check to info */
            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },
            isDisplayed:function () {

                console.log(customer);
                console.log(customer.customer);
                console.log(customer_Data);
                var total = quote.getTotals();
                console.log(total);
                console.log(quote.billingAddress);

                return false;
            }

        });
    }
);
```

after debugging not getting data.

[image]

Comment: how to show msg in cod payment method

Comment: @PriyaM see below answer it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try follwoing way:

**TestVendor/TestPayment/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/testpayment-method.js**

```
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function (Component, customerData, quote) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'TestVendor_TestPayment/payment/testpayment'
            },

            /** Returns send check to info */
            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },
            isDisplayed:function () {
                var customer = customerData.get('customer');
                console.log(customer().firstname);

                var totals = quote.getTotals()();
                var grand_total;
                if (totals) {
                    grand_total = totals.grand_total;
                } else {
                    grand_total = quote.grand_total;
                }

                console.log(grand_total);
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
);
```

**TestVendor/TestPayment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/testpayment.html**

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'">
                </button>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Run following command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Clear cache.

Comment: working fine. `<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->` and `<!-- /ko -->` this means code is commented right? then how it working?

Comment: This html file render using knockoutJs, <!-- ko if: isDisplayed() --> ... <!-- /ko --> is a if statement of knockoutJs.

Comment: Great. sound like charm!. if I want to display message. how to append message to div or any other control/element here (`.js` to `.html`)?

Comment: you can normal jquery operation. example: define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'jquery'
    ],
    function (Component, $) {}

Comment: I will try. but I have updated my thread for how getting customer data. Is it correct way or ? please suggest me. how to get customer data and order total here?

Comment: yes, check my update answer

Comment: checking.. above code.

Comment: not getting data see the screenshot from my updated thread.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I tried another way it's working fine. thank you.

Comment: how to show msg in cod payment method