# Magento2: How to add block in my payment module

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am try to create one custom payment module.

i want to show some options in drop down list during my payment selection.

and also i want to validate that drop down box before placing the order.

how to achieve this and how to add a custom block to my payment option.

Thanks in advance

Here is my stuff

```
<item name="testpayment" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_payment/js/view/payment/testpayment</item>
<item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
<item name="testpayment" xsi:type="array">
<item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>`

Component file is
`define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'testpayment',
                component: 'vendor_payment/js/view/payment/method-renderer/payment-method'
            }
        );
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

method render js file is

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'mage/url'
    ],
    function ($,Component,fullScreenLoader,url) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            redirectAfterPlaceOrder: false,
            defaults: {
                template: 'vendor_payment/payment/templatename'
            },            
            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },
            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },          
        });
    }
);
```

My template file is,

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content"> 
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
      <div class="control">
            <div class="fields group group-2">
               <label>Please choose your deposit percentage:</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <select name="custom_field"></select>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                       disabled>
                    <span data-bind="text: $t('Place order')"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now how to add dynamic values in "custom_field" select box. or its any possible to include .phtml file directly to that place?

Answer (score 1):

For example, I have inserted customer data here and I validating if customer data is available **Place Order** button will appear in payment block and the message should be displayed otherwise it will not appear.

The same way you can do your stuff.

`isDisplayed` is the custom method in `.js` file and `<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->` and `<!-- /ko -->` is the function to validate in `.html` file.

**method render js file is**

```
define(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
            'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
            'mage/url'
        ],
        function ($,Component,fullScreenLoader, customer, url) {
            'use strict';

             var isLoggedIn = ko.observable(window.isCustomerLoggedIn),
                customerData = {};

            if (isLoggedIn()) {
                customerData = window.customerData;
            } else {
                customerData = {};
            }

            return Component.extend({
                redirectAfterPlaceOrder: false,
                customerData: customerData,
                defaults: {
                    template: 'vendor_payment/payment/templatename'
                },            
                getMailingAddress: function() {
                    return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
                },
                isActive: function() {
                    return true;
                },
                isDisplayed:function () {
                    console.log(customerData.firstname);
                    if(customerData != null){
                        $('#custom_message').text('Custom Message');
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }           
            });
        }
    );
```

**template file is,**

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content"> 
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
      <div class="control">
            <div class="fields group group-2">
             <p id="custom_message" style="font-weight: bold;"></p>
               <label>Please choose your deposit percentage:</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <select name="custom_field"></select>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
                    <button class="action primary checkout"
                            type="submit"
                            data-bind="
                            click: placeOrder,
                            attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                            css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                            enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                            "
                           disabled>
                        <span data-bind="text: $t('Place order')"></span>
                    </button>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for more info see this [thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150199/insert-custom-block-at-payment-method-section-in-magento-2). feel free to ask if any queries.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. actually i did that. and my payment gateway was showing on that page also. but i need to add some dynamic select field on that page. so for dynamic if i use ".phtml" file then its easy for me do my stuff. but unfortunately i dont know how to implement that file into that place. please help me :(

Comment: @kalidass678 update your thread with your code, it will help to suggest you on your requirement.

Comment: i have updated the my code please check that. thanks in advance

Comment: @kalidass678 see my answer updated.

Comment: Hi thanks your answer is helps me for do my stuff other way. :)

Comment: @kalidass678 have you tried?