# Magento 2 Custom Payment Method Status Change New order instead of Processing

Tags: magento2, custom

I'm using `Magento 2.1` for when I'm using Custom Payment Method than Status Change `New order` instead of `Processing`.

kindly help me, anyone

Comment: Check: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-order-status-order-state.html

Comment: Also check: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150043/custom-payment-method-not-showing-in-checkout-page-in-magento-2